# Error PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels for Pypi packages

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

I am trying to create a conda env

```
conda create --name sf-prj-final --file requirements.txt
```

But I have encountered error says:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - grpcio==1.31.0=pypi_0
  - idna==2.10=pypi_0
  - google-auth==1.20.1=pypi_0
  - requests-oauthlib==1.3.0=pypi_0
  - pyasn1==0.4.8=pypi_0
  - oauthlib==3.1.0=pypi_0
  - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8=pypi_0
  - tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.7.0=pypi_0
  - pypng==0.0.18=pypi_0
  - correlation-cuda==0.0.0=pypi_0
  - werkzeug==1.0.1=pypi_0
  - tensorboard==2.3.0=pypi_0
  - torchvision==0.4.0=py37_cu100
  - importlib-metadata==1.7.0=pypi_0
  - zipp==3.1.0=pypi_0
  - absl-py==0.9.0=pypi_0
  - urllib3==1.25.10=pypi_0
  - cachetools==4.1.1=pypi_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1=pypi_0
  - forward-warp-cuda==0.0.0=pypi_0
  - chardet==3.0.4=pypi_0
  - markdown==3.2.2=pypi_0
  - rsa==4.6=pypi_0
  - requests==2.24.0=pypi_0
  - pytorch==1.2.0=py3.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.6.2_0
  - protobuf==3.12.4=pypi_0

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
```

I understand the problem. I have to install these packages from pip but is there any solution with conda to install all packages while creating conda environment?

Thank you.

Comment: same error here. did you solve this?

Comment: nope i could not find any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to install packages from the txt file to an already created environment - and that's why you are getting this error. the files that are listed in your error msg are packages that exist in the env (run `conda list` and you can see that they are already there).

So.. you have 2 possible solutions:

1. Enter your env (`conda activate mypyenv`) and remove these packages that are listed in the error msg (`conda remove somepackage`). they try applying these requirements again.
2. Use the create command to create a whole new environment with these packages: `conda create --name mynewpythonenv --file requirements.txt`

Comment: Hello, Thank you first of all. But I have already tried the command `conda create --name sf-prj-final --file requirements.txt`

Comment: this makes no sense.  if they are already installed, conda will say 'these are already installed'